# Debug dockerized nodejs application on startup

Tags: node.js, docker, visual-studio-code, docker-compose

I have a setup of containers running ( docker-compose ) and one with a nodejs application running inside of it. Currently i debug the application by connecting via VS Code to the debug port (9229) of the application. The problem with this approach is that i can't connect to the application on startup. If the error is on some event like an http connection that is no problem, but if i want to check the initialisation process the process is already running for some time until i can connect so the process ran past my debug points.

Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Run the following commands to find the running container and navigate into the container...

```
List all Docker images: docker image ls
View contents of a running Docker container: docker exec -it <container-id> bash
```

once inside the container, then you can stop the node process inside the container and start by `node app.js` where you will be able to see the logs from initialisation Or if you have a logs file then there aswell you can check.

The basic idea here is to navigate inside the docker container and then its like running node server like how you would run normally from ay linux terminal.

Comment: This does not help with the debugger i guess? I think there should be a simpler option to just let the container wait until the debugger is connected or something similar? This seems like not good practice to me.